# how to see the location of a file in visual studio solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio

I can look for file with `ctrl + ,` and get what i want

I can also right click the file tab and show the file in windows explorer

but the action above wont tell me where it is in the tree.

How can i see where the file lies inside the tree view in solution explorer?

Comment: What is `ctrl + ,`? Keyboard shortcut may be different in different settings.

Comment: @qxg sorry, it calls a window called "Navigate To"

Answer (score 3):

You need [Sync with Active Document](http://www.visualstudiotipsandtricks.com/blog/2014/06/05/sync-with-active-document/).

In Visual Studio 2015, check

[image]

If you are using older version of VS and don't have that button, you need to check [Tools -> Options -> Project and Solution -> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/29/track-active-item-in-solution-explorer-vstipproj0011.aspx)